# String split// manipulation

Tags: c#, string, split

```
string keywords = "heard";
string strText = "Have you not heard!! what I said?"
string[] words = strText.Split(' ');
string result = "";

for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
{
   if (words[i].Contains(keywords))
    result += "<span>" + words[i] + "</span>" + " ";
   else
    result += words[i] + " ";
}
```

**I get following output:**

```
Have you not <span>heard!!</span> what I said?
```

**Desired output:**

```
Have you not <span>heard</span>!! what I said?
```

Can someone guide how can I get the desired output. The strText can only be split with a space.

Comment: What **javascript** tag does here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`String.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.100).aspx)

```
var result = strText.Replace(keywords, "<span>" + keywords + "</span>");
```

If you have many keywords to replace, then just do replacement in a loop:

```
string[] keywords = { "heard", "said" };
string result = "Have you not heard!! what I said?";

foreach(var keyword in keywords)
    result = result.Replace(keyword, "<span>" + keyword + "</span>");
```

Alternative solution is regular expression replacement:

```
string keywords = "heard|said";
string result = "Have you not heard!! what I said?";
result = Regex.Replace(result, keywords, m => "<span>" + m.Value + "</span>");
```

Comment: @mrd thanks) but I decided it would be overkill for simple replacement task)

Comment: `m => "<span>" + m.Value + "</span>"` can be replaced by `"<span>$0</span>"`.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you even looping through all words? This will give you the same:

```
        string strText = "Have you not heard!! what I said?";
        string newText = strText.Replace("heard", "<span>heard</span>");
```